# Fetch data from Factbook offline

Tags: sparql, semantic-web

Since Factbook's SPARQL endpoint is down, I downloaded the zip file of their data. I do not understand how can i fire SPARQL queries at it. Any idea as to how it can be achieved? The unzipped version doesn't have a single RDF file so Fuseki is giving me an error

Comment: It should be clear that for other people it is not clear which Zip file you mean...of course, you have to download the RDF dump and not the file from https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/download/ Try to start from here https://datahub.io/dataset/cia-world-factbook

Comment: I couldn't find any RDF dump on any links on that page. All it gives is one json file (named datapackage) and all others are links to zip files having HTML.